# What is this naming convention?

Tags: naming-conventions

I am looking through code that has multiple naming conventions from multiple developers - a real treat.  Amongst them are Hungarian ("s_year", "s_day") as well as this other style ("yearS", "dayS").

Does anyone know what this style is called?  For bonus points, do you know where/when it originated?

Disclaimer: Bonus points are hypothetical and awarded on a per-request basis only.  Please give 5-12 weeks for delivery.

Edit: I would like to add that there is a third notation ("sYear", "sDay") in the same file.  It's the hat trick of naming conventions!

Comment: Community wiki. And my vote goes for "origin: Hell"

Comment: The first one is not (necessarily) Hungarian notation.  Prefixes like s_ (for statics) and m_ (for members) and g_ (for globals) are common in C++ code, and compatible with Hungarian notation, but not necessarily part of it.  I've never seen the second method.

Comment: @earlz - I disagree that this should be Wiki. It's a perfectly answerable question, provided an answer exists (in which case, "there is no name for the notation" is the correct answer).

Comment: Fix the naming and let us never speak of this again... ;)

Comment: It's just a variation or cousin or abstract generalization of Hungarian notation using a capital suffix instead of a lowercase underscore prefix. I don't see why "Hungarian notation" need be tightly associated with which side and case the [affix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affix) uses in a particular implementation, to me it's more of a semantic notion that one of particular spelling. In fact it's pretty ironic since the Hungarian language is overwhelmingly a suffixing language and only has a small number of prefixes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an perfect example of either no naming convention, or of a frequently changed naming convention. Unfortunately, I have seen this quite a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It is called "lobotomized notation". It was invented by R. P. McMurphy.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely it's not a notation at all - quite often [lazy] programmers will have a need for a unique variable where a similar one is already in scope - hence they needed another holder for a 'year' and 'year' was already taken so they opted for 'yearS'. If it's any notation at all, it would be to stand out in its blecherousness as a reminder to change it to something meaningful in the future (which never came. Mwahahahaha!)